# Unable to update app from play store after new APK uploaded

Tags: android, google-play

We are facing an issue with application update. We had uploaded the latest version of our app in Play Store with update version code & name. But when users try to update their existing app, Play doesn't show the "Update" option, rather it shows "Open" & "Uninstall". Users can successfully install the app after uninstalling the existing app. The issue happens only when the users tries to update their existing app.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Have you waited for the store to update it? Is the version shown in the Store the new version? Is the update supported by the previous version devices as well?

Comment: not really a programming question. Not sure if belongs to SO.

Comment: We updated the app a week back. The issue happens when users with an older version of app (not the immediate previous version) tries to update their existing app.

Comment: @Subin Are you certain that it is signed with the proper key? One way to check would be install from market and then try side loading your signed APK file. Also did your project package name change?

Comment: actually, It happened to me  when i get old version from debug mode on visual studio (I am using xamarin forms )

Answer (score 4):

Google Play can take upto 24 hours to push application updates across all its servers.

Just wait for a while, and all your eligible users should receive the update. However, if your update adds feature requests that some devices don't support, they will not get the update.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that in another forum discussion that few apps faced similar issue and its due to the bug in Google Play.

When user with lower version lands to Google Play the user will see Uninstall/Open option. The Google Play client installed in the device is having an “Uninstall Updates” option(screenshot attached) if user access thought Settings >Apps >Google Play. Post clicking “Uninstall Updates” the version information of apps are refreshed and the

The below are reference links:

Ref : http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobile/z94celd1kTo

Hope this helps you.